# Flex Filereference automatically retry when failed (like error #2038)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, filereference

Is there a way to automatically retry Fileupload.upload() opertaion if it fails with IO_Error?
I tried calling upload() again (and it did reach all the way to the web-service)
==> but it did NOT trigger DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA when the Retry was completed (i checked with a sniffer that the retry operation did finish successfully)
Thanks for any ideas.