# Flex FileReference.upload does not trigger any events on subsequent calls

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, filereference

I'm using the PLUpload library for browser file uploads.
It's Flash module uses FileReference.

When testing the uploads I kill the web server to see how it handles it and can be programmatically recovered from.  Not something a lot of people test it seems as the HTML5 module doesn't check for a 0 status response either. Anyway, fixed that.

Basically FileReference.upload() works as expected in the first call.
Subsequent calls do not trigger any events.
I tried FileReference.cancel, no difference.
Can confirm that calling upload repeatedly if the upload is successful works fine.

Event listeners are setup and torn down before/after each upload start.

This is a duplicate of this question which was never answered.

[Flex Filereference automatically retry when failed (like error #2038)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471060/flex-filereference-automatically-retry-when-failed-like-error-2038)

I'm not a Flash guy at all, first time I've played with AS.
Look like a bug though.

Comment: Appears that Adobe may be aware of this, but perhaps someone has a workaround?

Comment: Is there a possibility for creating fresh FileReferene instance after first use?